# How to pronounce code?

Tags: pronunciation

Can someone tell me how to pronounce the word "code"? I am in Hong Kong, and people always pronounce it like "coke," but without the voiceless consonant "k". Is that correct?

Comment: Hi louis. have you tried our site specifically for [English language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: sorry typed something worng, people always pronounce it like " cook " without the voiceless consonant " k ".

Comment: Basically, you pronounce "cold" like you have a bad head cold.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually pronounced with three sounds:

- the hard **/k/** sound at the beginning, as in **cat** or **coke**
- the **/o/** vowel, as in **open**
- the hard **/d/** consonant as in **dog**

However, there are many variations between dialects, especially with the vowel: in my dialect, it's usually more of a diphthong /ou/ or /oʊ/ than a pure /o/. And in some places, the /d/ at the end is more of a glottal stop (the sound between the vowels in the word "uh-oh"). It sounds like that's what you're hearing, and that's also a perfectly valid way to pronounce it even if it's less common in the US and UK.

Comment: Where is a final /d/ realised as a glottal stop? I would hear that as 'coat', not 'code'.

Comment: @ColinFine Some of my Vietnamese coworkers realize all final plosives as glottal stops, though I don't know if that's a local dialect or related to Vietnamese phonology.

Answer (score 1):

C sounds like "Coke"
The o sounds like "ou" in pinyin or "oh" in English.
D sounds like the D in Dà (big), but soft and short.

C, ou, D